# How to get list of enabled/disabled features of SQLAnywhere

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

I'm looking to get a list of features, which are installed or enabled/disabled on a given SQLAnywhere instance. `dblic` is only showing the 'possible' feature based on lice, but not the actually available features of database server ... or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of SQL Anywhere you are using but for v12.0.1 you can execute
`SELECT PROPERTY ( 'ServerEdition' );` The result is explained in the docs thus:

> ### ServerEdition
>
> Returns a space-separated list of words describing the database server type. 
>   Values include:
>
> ```
> Evaluation
> Developer 
> Web 
> Educational 
> Standard 
> Advanced 
> Workgroup 
> OEM 
> Authenticated
> ```
>
> If you have a separate license for any of the following features, then the appropriate string(s) are added to the license string that is returned:
>
> ```
> HighAvailability   See SQL Anywhere high availability option. 
> InMemory           See SQL Anywhere in-memory mode option. 
> ECC                See SQL Anywhere security option. 
> FIPS               See SQL Anywhere security option.
> ```

You can get more help at the dedicated SQL Anywhere forum http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/